# Recurrence relation task

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can someone explain me this:
$T(n)=-T(n-1)+2\times T(n-2)+3 \times 2^n+n$

According to Wolfram Alpha the answer is:

> $$ T(n) = c_1(-2)^n + c_2 + \dfrac{1}{18}n(3n + 7) + 3 \times 2^n - \dfrac{5}{27}$$

but can someone explain me how it is calculated? I know the basic algorithm, but don't know what to do with that $3 \times 2^n+n$

Comment: What are you asking for? Do you want the closed form equation for the $n$-th term?

Comment: Predict the big-Theta behavior of a function T(n) satisfying the recurrence relation above

Comment: Ah, ok. I have no idea how to do that :P

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks anyway!

Comment: http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/S/1019/Website_files/21-linear-recurrences.pdf - see page $27$, 'Linear non-homogeneous recurrences' or http://furthermathematicst.blogspot.in/2011/06/43-non-homogeneous-linear-recurrence.html (shorter version)

Comment: Thansks. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split this into three pieces $T(n)=P(n)+Q(n)+R(n)$ where

$$P(n)+P(n-1)-2P(n-1)=0$$$$Q(n)+Q(n-1)-2Q(n-1)=3\times 2^n$$$$R(n)+R(n-1)-2R(n-1)=n$$

You find $$P(n)=a(-2)^n+b \text { (where this is in fact }b\cdot 1^n)$$

The test solution for the linear recurrence $L(n)=s(n)t^n$ where $s$ is a polynomial in $n$ is $n^ru(n)t^{n}$ where $u(n)$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $s(n)$ and $r$ is the multiplicity of $t$ as a root of the associated equation, which in this case is $t^2+t-2=0$ with roots $1, -2$.

So for $Q$ we try $n^0\times d\times 2^n=d\cdot 2^n$

For $R$ noting that $1$ is a root of order $1$ we try $n(en+f)1^n$